# Compile-time constant strings and life-time (char[] version)

Tags: c++, c++20

I have recently started playing with Scott Schurr's [`str_const`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/boostcon/cppnow_presentations_2012/master/wed/schurr_cpp11_tools_for_class_authors.pdf):

```
class str_const {
    const char *p;
    std::size_t sz;

   public:
    template <std::size_t N>
    constexpr str_const(const char (&a)[N]) : p(a), sz(N - 1) {}

    // ...
};
```

and David Sanders' follow-up [implementation](https://gist.github.com/dsanders11/8951887), "condensed" to (avoiding `std::integer_sequence`):

```
template <std::size_t N>
struct str_chars {
    char p[N]{};
    static inline constexpr std::size_t sz = N - 1;

    constexpr str_chars(char const (&c)[N]) {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) p[i] = c[i];
    };

    // ...
};

template <std::size_t N>
constexpr auto str_chars_make(const char (&c)[N]) {
    return str_chars(c);
}
```

What I'm wondering now is, what the life-time of the result of `str_chars_make` is: when passing it to a function or assigning it through something similar to `std::string_view`, the character array is not initialized:

```
str_const tmp = str_chars_make("abc");
std::cout << "1: " << tmp.data() << std::endl;
```

Here, with gcc the output is empty, with clang, the output is garbage.

I have tried a couple of other possibilities [that do work (godbolt➚)](https://godbolt.org/z/8av4MhvWP) — yet I do wonder if I'm relying on UB.

Some language lawyer's insight would be welcome.

Greetings,
Yogev

Comment: `-fsanitize=address` -> `stack-use-after-scope` you can easy check yourself. `what the life-time of the result of str_chars_make is` the lifetime is up until the end of the expression. I do not understand why do you need a language lawyer to indicate that a return value from a function stops existing after the expression?

Comment: First version has UB if it is initialized from a temporary and used after the end of life of that temporay. Secon version works in all case as the content is copied in  a member variable.

Comment: `str_const tmp = str_chars_make("abc");` shouldn't compile. I don't see anything in the code shown that would make `str_chars` implicitly convertible to `str_const`. Nor does `str_const` have a member named `data`. Could you show a [mcve]?

Comment: Why do you take a string constant, copy it into a temporary `str_chars` to initialize a `str_const`? That implicitly converts the `str_chars` to `const char *` when the array decays, taking the address of the temporary. You need just `str_const tmp = "abc";`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik it has `operator str_const`

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Not in the code shown.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik It's in the ..., see the godbolt link

Comment: `str_const tmp = str_chars_make("abc"); tmp.data()` exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an object after its lifetime has ended. `str_chars_make` produces a temporary of type `str_chars`. `tmp.p` is initialized to point to a data member of that temporary. At the semicolon, the temporary is destroyed and `tmp.p` becomes dangling. Any attempt to use it then exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: The other two usages in [the example](https://godbolt.org/z/8av4MhvWP) are well-defined. In both cases, the data that `str_const::p` points to outlives the `str_const` instance.

Comment: Thank You very much for all of Your comments, apologies for the delay: infamous German holiday season came in between...

Comment: @IgorTandetnik etal. I'm still puzzled, why `&&` in the UDL (see Godbolt example) makes the result an lvalue, but without behaves exactly like example 1.

Comment: "**[temp.param]/8** An *id-expression* naming a non-type *template-parameter* of class type `T` denotes a static storage duration object of type `const T`, known as a *template parameter object*" Thus, in your `operator""`, `S` is this template parameter object, having static duration. The version with `&&` returns a reference to that long-lived object. The version without `&&` returns a temporary that's a copy of that object, and then runs into the same problem as `str_chars_make`